# Making something abnormal seem normal?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that can be used to describe an author's portrayal of a scene as normal even though the content of what is described is innately disturbing/unnatural?

> *He cut open the dog's underbelly and we all took turns examining its insides, which were just as we had expected them to be. To get over the disappointment it was suggested we head out for drinks later, which I was forced to decline...*
>
> The writer's description of the scene is **word**.
> The writer **words** the scene.
> This disgusting scene is **worded** by the writer.

Earlier I was able to think specifically of the word, but now I can't even remember whether it was an adjective/verb, so sorry for being so open in my example usages, but hopefully this contains enough information for someone to propose something.

Comment: Something like "normalise", the writer manages to "normalise" the portrayal of dissection

Comment: The closest I could come with is *banal* and *banalize* - cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eichmann_in_Jerusalem

Comment: Endorsed / sanctioned / legitimised / condoned ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth not quite what I am aiming for, "endorsed" seems to connote that the writer supports the things portrayed, which is not necessarily the case; they have simply described something abnormal as normal.

Comment: The writer's description of the scene is *prosaic*. Add an adverb, if desired: deliberately prosaic, surprisingly prosaic, shockingly prosaic, etc. Or phrase it as an adverb to begin with : *the writer prosaically described the horrific scene*.

Comment: The writer's description of the scene "lack emphasis". The writer "dulls" the scene.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe **[detached](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/detached)**?
This has a connotation of emotional coldness or numbness

> adj. impartial or objective; disinterested; unbiased; not involved or concerned; aloof.

It fits best with your first sentence:

> The writer's description of the scene is **detached**.

---

I might also suggest something in the vein of [**nonchalant**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonchalant), which fits a bit better with more of your sentences.

> adj. relaxed and calm in a way that shows that you do not care or are not worried about anything
>
> The writer's decription of the scene is **nonchalant**.
>
> The writer describes the scene **nonchalantly**.

Comment: I used nonchalant in my analysis to describe something similar, and agree it is a good choice. Detached, whilst almost conveying what I intend, doesn't quite cover that aspect of "normalisation" that I am after.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider ***trivial/trivialize*** (UK *trivialise*).

> The writer's description of the scene is ***trivial***.
>
> The writer ***trivializes*** the scene.
>
> This disgusting scene is ***trivialized*** by the writer.

**M-W**:

> **[trivial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trivial)**
> *adjective*
>
> **1** :  **commonplace, ordinary**
>
> Compared to her problems, our problems seem ***trivial***.
>
> **[trivialize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trivialize)**
> *transitive verb* trivialized trivializing
>
> :  **to make *trivial*** :  reduce to triviality
>
> The news story ***trivialized*** the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you explicitly mention that you don't know if it was a verb or an adjective I think you will fare best with *makes the scene seem adjective* or *describes the scene as adjective.* The reason is that the effect of a scene seeming normal in any given context is likely conveyed by the persons reacting unexcited and without the disgust the reader feels.

Just picking a few adjectives from the [synonym list of *commonplace*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/commonplace) here, *ordinary, unremarkable, conventional, typical, everyday...*

> The writer *makes the scene seem ordinary.*
>
> The writer's *describes the scene as commonplace*.
>
> This disgusting scene is skilfully *made to seem unremarkable*.

This is on the assumption that the scene's sense of normalcy is brought forth by it being an *everyday thing for the participating persons.* If you are trying to describe a writer that wants the reader to think that the scene is normal in our world that would be different there is more likely a verb out there that fits that description because it's an Inception level fewer.

Answer (score 0):

*neutralize*

I'm sorry, but the definitions I read don't support this idea.  Nevertheless, I think it works in the context.  The context involves some sort of tension which can be neutralized -- the tension gets removed by the matter-of-fact treatment the author gives the material.

*clinical*

Dictionary.com gives

"3. extremely objective and realistic; dispassionately analytic; unemotionally critical"

> The writer's description of the scene is **clinical**.
>
> The writer **neutralizes** the scene.
>
> This disgusting scene is **dissected** by the writer.

*Dissected* means the writer took apart the offensive details, removing the emotional effect.

Comment: "clinical" is very good. why do you have so many words in your answer

Answer (score 0):

**dispassionate**

> : not influenced by strong feeling
> *especially* : not affected by personal or emotional involvement

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispassionate

Answer (score 0):

**unimpassioned**

> having or showing no emotion or intensity

Oxford Dictionary of English

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Your examples seem to suggest that a  verb is required. _unimpassioned_ is an adjective.

Comment: @user405662 "I can't even remember whether it was an adjective/verb"

Answer (score 0):

**Soft-pedal** seems to work well in the provided context.

> To make less emphatic or obvious; play down:

*soft-pedal a potentially explosive issue*

[American Heritage Dictionary]

Answer (score -2):

How about ***regular*** / ***regularize***?

From Dictionary.com:

> [***regular***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/regular): usual; normal
>
> [***regularize***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/regularize?s=t): to make
>   ***regular***

The OP's examples:

> The writer's description of the scene is ***regular***.
>
> The writer ***regularizes*** the scene.
>
> This disgusting scene is **regularized** by the writer.

Comment: What's with the down votes? And your problem with this answer is ...?

Comment: I don't know why it was so harshly downvoted, maybe another answerer got scared... but "regular" connotes patterns and being methodical to me more than it does some concept of normalcy, so I'm not sure how applicable it is in this case.

Comment: @theonlygusti Thanks. Much appreciated. The definition  indicates *usual*, *normal*.

Comment: @RichardKayser, I have not downvoted; however, perhaps _regular(ize)_ does not convey the intended meaning.